# Has anyone worked with HX711 load cell amplifier / weighting sensor through Arduino?

Tags: arduino, amplifier, load-cell

I am talking about this product: http://www.ebay.in/itm/232127458591?aff_source=Sok-Goog

I need to know the following:

1) What outputs are represented by DT and SCK?

2) What inputs are B- and B+?

3) Where to connect DT and SCK on Arduino board?

4) I have load cell with 5 wires (Red, Black, Black, Green, White). What wires shall connect to B+, B-?

5) Why two wires are black? How do I find which one of them is E- and what is the purpose of second black wire?

Comment: If the seller cannot supply data, scrap it.

Comment: You should post this question to the eBay seller.  EE.SE isn't his volunteer technical support.

Comment: @NickAlexeev thanks for post guidelines, however I am not asking on behalf of eBay. I shared the link only to show the device for which I need some help, not that I am buying this product from eBay and asking people here to share knowledge on behalf of eBay.

Comment: @harshvardhan  So... have you posted this question to the eBay seller?

Comment: @NickAlexeev, not obtaining it from ebay. ebay link was only device reference. I got this thing from my friend and we already have googled well for corresponding datasheet. Here are few documentations:

http://arduinotronics.blogspot.in/2015/06/arduino-hx711-digital-scale.html?m=1 , 

http://www.layadcircuits.com/tutorial.php?p=4 , 

https://software.intel.com/en-us/iot/hardware/sensors/hx711-analog-to-digital-converter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the picture of that breakout board, you can see that it is mainly exposing the pins of the ADC.

[image: PCB]

For example, DT and SCK are connected to pins 12 and 11 of the IC. So check the [datasheet for HX711](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/hx711_english.pdf) and you'll find the description:

[image: datasheet]

Reading through the datasheet should tell you more than you need to know about how to use this device. Sparkfun [also supplies a breakout](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/load-cell-amplifier-hx711-breakout-hookup-guide), which has a tutorial. The board is very similar to yours and you can see what connects where and follow the example given.

The ADC is two-channel but only one is used, so the B+ and B- inputs, which are for the second channel are redundant and therefore do not need to be connected. Look at the equivalent [Sparkfun schematic](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ForceFlex/SparkFun_HX711_Load_Cell_v11.pdf) to see what pins are used for which purpose and then do the same thing with those connections on your board. Then the Arduino library and example code should work in the same way.

Comment: Hey Roger! I downloaded the datasheet from sparkfun prior to posting this, only their I/O pin configuration is little different from the device that I had shown, because of which this issue came up.  But thanks for guidance, so I can now analyze pin config and channel out I/O ops.